# Remove html tags using regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I want to remove all html tags except `<a>` `<img>` and `<iframe>` from document using this code:

```
var regex = "<(?!a )(?!img )(?!iframe )([\s\S]*?)>";
var temp;
while (source.match(regex)) {
    temp = source.match(regex)[0];
    source = source.replace(temp, "");
}
return source;
```

It works in online regex testers, but for some reason it doesn't work on my page. For example it returns an original string when the input is:

```
    "<p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-left:202.5pt;line-height:200%;background:white"><b><span style="font-size: 16pt; line-height: 200%; color: rgb(131, 60, 11); background-image: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-size: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial; background-position: initial; background-repeat: initial;">test</span></b><span style="font-size:16.0pt;
line-height:200%;color:#833C0B;letter-spacing:-.15pt;mso-ansi-language:EN-US"><o:p></o:p></span></p>"
```

Please help!

Comment: Can you tell what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: Isn't `[\s\S]` the equivalent of `.`? Have you tried adding `console.log(temp)` inside your `while` loop (or setting a break point) to see what is actually happening?

Comment: [\s\S] allows regex to match across multiple lines

Comment: Use regex literal syntax: `var regex = /<(?!a )(?!img )(?!iframe )([\s\S]*?)>/;` (note the forward slashes). You are declaring a string, which means `[\s\S]` ends up as simply `[sS]`. (To use a string you need to escape the backslashes: `"[\\s\\S]"`.)

Comment: Obligatory: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Bumped into this question, was about to post your comment, @danielnixon. ... Damn, 2 hours apart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it without a regex. It's usually not a good idea to try parsing HTML with regexes, unless the use case is very simple...

The way I implemented `stripHtmlElementsMatching`, you can pass it any CSS selector and it will strip all matching entities.

Therefore, to remove anything but `a, img, iframe` you can pass `:not(a):not(img):not(iframe)`.

PS: The `htmlstripping-root` custom tag is only to avoid creating a parser element that interferes with the passed selector. For instance, if I used `div` as a parser element and you would pass the selector `div > div`, all divs would be removed even if they were not nested in your html string.

```js
var stripHtmlElementsMatching = (function(doc) {
  
  doc.registerElement('htmlstripping-root');
  
  return function(text, selector) {
    
    var parser = document.createElement('htmlstripping-root'),
        matchingEls, i, len, el;
    
    selector = typeof selector == 'string' ? selector : ':not(*)';
    parser.innerHTML = text;
    
    matchingEls = parser.querySelectorAll(selector);
    
    for (i = 0, len = matchingEls.length; i < len; i++) {
      el = matchingEls[i];
      el.parentNode.replaceChild(newFragFrom(el.childNodes), el);
    }
    
    return parser.innerHTML;
  };
  
  function newFragFrom(nodes) {
    var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    
    while (nodes.length) frag.appendChild(nodes[0]);
    
    return frag;
  }
  
})(document);


var text = '<p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-left:202.5pt;line-height:200%;background:white"><b><span style="font-size: 16pt; line-height: 200%; color: rgb(131, 60, 11); background-image: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-size: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial; background-position: initial; background-repeat: initial;">test</span></b><span style="font-size:16.0pt; line-height:200%;color:#833C0B;letter-spacing:-.15pt;mso-ansi-language:EN-US"><o:p></o:p></span></p>';

var tagsToKeep = ['a', 'img', 'iframe'];

var sanitizeSelector = tagsToKeep.map(function(tag) {
  return ':not(' + tag + ')';
}).join('');

var sanitizedText = stripHtmlElementsMatching(text, sanitizeSelector);

document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(sanitizedText));
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the best that I could come up with!

```
<((?!a)|a\w)(?!\/a)(?!img)(?!iframe)(?!\/iframe)+([\s\S]*?)>
```

The first capturing group, the not a or a followed by a word, allows audio, abbr, address, etc. to all pass through.

Just replace the matches from the above regex with nothing.

Please see: http://regexr.com/3a5hp